# Can I use twig in standalone project

Tags: php, twig

Can I use twig templating  engine in a standalone project , for example to design more on 1000 html page , ie site full with static pages    , if you had any simple example i will thank you

Comment: Standalone from what? Twig has [its own website](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). It isn't as if it is something like the [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) that appears to be tied into a larger project.

Comment: i meant to say to use it only for simple php + html websites

Comment: I'm trying to do this as well. All I want is simple inheritance between templates. I think I might give up :(

Comment: Try this > https://github.com/marvin/php-twig-example you might find it useful

Answer (score 18):

I found [this Sitepoint tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/twig-popular-stand-alone-php-template-engine/) very straightforward.  I've simplified and summarised the steps:

It assumes basic command line and [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) knowledge.

- install Twig - Composer is *probably* the simplest way for most people. Run `composer require twig/twig` in your docroot. This will create a `composer.json` and `composer.lock` if you don't already have them, and a `vendor` directory into which Composer will download Twig and a couple of the Symfony dependencies it uses.  Composer will also generate some autoload files.
- create a `templates` directory for your Twig source files (personally I like to put this above the docroot for security)
- create a sample `index.html.twig` template in that directory
- create a `bootstrap.php` file (a few lines of PHP to load and initialise Twig (and tells it where to find the templates)
- create an `index.php` file to demonstate loading and parsing a template. This:

  - loads the bootstrap
  - defines some data (in an array) to populate tags in the template
  - uses the Twig [render()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html#rendering-templates) method, specifying the template and the data array

Visit the second PHP file in your browser and you should get a rendered Twig template.

**boostrap.php:**

```
<?php

// Load our autoloader
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// Specify our Twig templates location
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/../templates');

// Instantiate our Twig
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```

**index.php:**

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap.php';

// Sample data
$foo = [
  [ 'name'          => 'Alice' ],
  [ 'name'          => 'Bob' ],
  [ 'name'          => 'Eve' ],
];

// Render our view
echo $twig->render('index.html', ['foo' => $foo] );
```

**templates/index.html.twig:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Twig Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul>
    {% for item in foo %}
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

The next stage would be to modify your index.php into a proper 'front controller' so it can handle multiple templates.

The tutorial also mentions things like caching the generated templates.

Comment: ```echo $twig->render('index.html', ['foo' => $foo] );``` worked for me

Comment: If you are getting an error stating twig cannot find `index.html` use `echo $twig->render('index.html.twig', ['foo' => $foo] );`

Answer (score 7):

I did fight today trying to find out how this works, because the official documentation is not perfect...
So I found the solution.

simple structure:

twig/app/app.php
twig/vendor (created with composer as in documentation)
twig/views/page.html.twig

---

app.php :

```
<?php require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader;
use Twig\Environment;

$loader = new FilesystemLoader('../views/');

$twig = new Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('page.html.twig', ['text' => 'Fabien']);
```

---

page.html.twig :

```
<h1>Hello {{ text }}</h1>
```